# ClickHouse: How to get argMax for array of tuples

Tags: clickhouse

The task is to get the tuple with the maximum first item. Is there any better way than the following?

```
select arrayMax(u.a.1) first_item_max_in_array, 
    indexOf(u.a.1,first_item_max_in_array) index_in_array, 
    u.a[index_in_array].2 arg_max_second_item_first_item 
from (
    select [(1,10),(2,20),(3,30)] a
) u
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [Array-combinator](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/combinators/#agg-functions-combinator-array):

```sql
WITH [(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30)] AS arr
SELECT argMaxArray(arr.2, arr.1) AS result

/*
┌─result─┐
│     30 │
└────────┘
*/
```

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I missed this option trying instead arrayArgMax by analogy with arraySum, arrayAvg etc names. It's funny there exist function names like arraySum and sumArray.

Comment: @unz np, I am glad to help.